# handlebars error with passport-steam

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, passport.js

Giving me an errors and I cant display the avatar and steam name

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', user: req.user });
});

router.get('/tos', function(req, res) {
    res.render('tos', { title: 'Terms of Service', user: req.user });
});
```

```html
<img src='{{user.photos[2].value}}' alt="Profile Avatar"/>
<span>{{{user.dispalyName}}}</span>
```

Error

```
Error: Parse error on line 36: ... <img src='{{user.photos[2].value}}' a -----------------------^ Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID' at Parser.parseError (C:\Users\VladG\Desktop\Tutorials\Express Web\CSGOGamble\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\parser.js:267:1 9) at Parser.parse (C:\Users\VladG\Desktop\Tutorials\Express Web\CSGOGamble\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\parser.js:336:30) at HandlebarsEnvironment.parse (C:\Users\VladG\Desktop\Tutorials\Express Web\CSGOGamble\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\base. js:46:43) at compileInput (C:\Users\VladG\Desktop\Tutorials\Express Web\CSGOGamble\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\compiler.js:514:19) at ret (C:\Users\VladG\Desktop\Tutorials\Express Web\CSGOGamble\node_modules\handlebars\dist\cjs\handlebars\compiler\compiler.js:523:18) at ExpressHandlebars._renderTemplate (C:\Users\VladG\Desktop\Tutorials\Express Web\CSGOGamble\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\express-handleba rs.js:247:12) at ExpressHandlebars.<anonymous> (C:\Users\VladG\Desktop\Tutorials\Express Web\CSGOGamble\node_modules\express-handlebars\lib\express-handlebars.j s:173:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it's the index in `photos[2]` what makes the error. You can bypass the problem by using the `user._json` values from the same user object like this:

```
<img src="{{user._json.avatarfull}}" alt="Profile Avatar"/>
```

This works fine and the URL of the image is the same as in `user.photos`.